# window.print is not working in webview. xamarin.android

Tags: javascript, webview, xamarin.android

I am opening a web page with the help of webview. When I click on a button in it;

```
var newWindow=window.open();
newWindow.document.body.innerHTML="<table>....</table>";
setTimeout(() => {
    newWindow.print();
    newWindow.close();
}, 1000);
```

transactions are taking place. but somehow the new screen does not appear and the print screen does not appear either.

and my xamarin.adroid code;

```
 WebView web_view;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        Android.Webkit.WebView.SetWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);

        web_view = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webview);
        web_view.SetWebChromeClient(new ExtendWebChromeClient(this));
        web_view.SetWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        web_view.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        web_view.Settings.AllowFileAccess = true;
        web_view.Settings.JavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true;
        web_view.Settings.SetSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        web_view.Settings.SetSupportZoom(true);
        web_view.Settings.BuiltInZoomControls = true;
        web_view.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
        web_view.Settings.LoadWithOverviewMode = true;
        web_view.Settings.DisplayZoomControls = true;
        web_view.Settings.AllowContentAccess = true;
        web_view.Settings.DefaultTextEncodingName = "utf-8";
        web_view.Settings.SafeBrowsingEnabled = true;
        web_view.Settings.UseWideViewPort = true;
        web_view.SetWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
        web_view.LoadUrl("https://sample.com");
        web_view.Settings.SetPluginState(PluginState.On);
    }
```

I entered chrome and debug my code with the help of **chrome://inspect/#devices.** I didn't get any errors. what can I do?

Comment: I have read your question and here is a similar case that can provide you with reference. You may refer to this website: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45810544/window-print-doesnt-work-in-android-webview-api-23-but-works-in-default-brows".

Answer (score 0):

You can not use window.print() function in android directly.
Try print web view option and use javascript interface for print button click via html button of website.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).